# Derive $P[D = 1|X]$ from $X = f(X,-1)P[D =-1|X] + f(X,1)P[D =1|X]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Given the random variables $X: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ and $D: \Omega \to \{-1,1 \}$, and the (measurable) function $f: \mathbb R \times \{-1, 1 \} \to \mathbb R$.

> Show that if
>
> $$ 
> X = f(X,-1)P[D =-1|X] + f(X,1)P[D =1|X], 
> $$
>
> then
>
> $$ 
> \frac{X - f(X, -1)}{f(X, 1) - f(X, -1)} = P[D = 1 |X].
> $$

All I can see is the immediate algebraic manipulation

$$
\frac{X -  f(X, -1)P[D=-1|X]}{f(X, 1)} = P[D = 1|X]
,$$

but then I am perplexed how to proceed.

Most grateful for any help provided!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition of $X$, we can write,
\begin{align*}
X - f(X,-1) & = f(X, -1)P[D = -1|X] - f(X, -1)+ f(X, 1)P[D = 1|X]  \\
& = f(X, -1)(P[D = -1|X] - 1)+ f(X, 1)P[D = 1|X]  \\
& = -f(X, -1)P[D = 1|X] + f(X, 1)P[D = 1|X]  \\
& = P[D = 1|X](f(X, 1)-f(X, -1))  \\
\end{align*}

On rearranging, we get the required expression.

Comment: So basically the claim is that $1 - P[D = -1|X] = P[D = 1 |X]$?

Comment: Yeah since $D|X$ is a random variable that can only take the values $\{-1, 1\}$, therefore, the sum of $P[D = -1|X]$ and $P[D = 1|X]$ should be $1$.